# What should a proper grid for a bevel look like?

Tags: topology, bevel

I have a box with a simple form and a bevel.
The box looks like on a picture. The bottom surface is narrower than the top surface.
The grid of the top surface is OK. But I doubt the grid of the narrow surface, there are dents here. What should a proper grid look like? [image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can lower this using autosmooth shading and adding a normal edit modifier:

[image]

[Normal edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html) with "radial" option will align all the normals with axis coming to the face from a center (which can be the object center itself of another object's center).

Comment: Hello, what does Normal Edit do exactly?

Comment: Hello, @moonboots, answer edited

Comment: It works very strange. With subD I've lost all edges in the view. I think the problem is with 3-pole on the narrow surface

Comment: yes... that may be what you want or not.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to move 3-pole inside the narrow surface and it helps. I don't know if it is correct or not, but it works.

[image]